# What is wrong with this MySql INSERT statements?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

This is my first time making a little bigger app in java ee and i want to make a book store, this is how my database looks like:

```
Book:
- id:(int) primary key, autoincrement, not null,
- title:(varchar) not null,
- price: (decimal) not null

Cart:
-id:(int) primary key, autoincrement, not null
```

and

```
Artical:
- id:(int) primary key, autoincrement, not null,
- title:(varchar) not null,
- price: (decimal) not null,
- cart_id:(int) foreign key referencing cart
```

I already have some books in Book table, Artical and Cart are empty, so idea is when user clicks button "add to cart" i want to insert id in Cart table and data(book) in Artical table based on book that is clicked. And this is how my INSERT statement looks like:

```
insert into Cart (id) values(null);

INSERT INTO Artical(id,title,price,cart_id) 
VALUES(null,
    'some book',
     20,
    (select Cart.id from Cart join Artical AS ar ON  Cart.id = ar.cart_id));
```

I get error `cart_id can not be null`. Is my statement wrong or maybe this whole design?

Comment: You shouldn't specify the `id` column in your insert statement. So remove it from the column list, and `null` from the values list.

Comment: if you add primary key to any column then this field can't be null or empty you need to assign value to it or it should be auto incremented in case of integer fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select Cart.id from Cart join Artical as ar on  Cart.id = ar.cart_id` line is returning null or zero results. Which seems obvious - the idea here is surely to use the ID of the freshly created Cart row, and that's.. not how you do that, and I'm a bit confused as to why you think it would.

JDBC has tools to fetch the auto-generated entry in a new row, such as `PreparedStatement`'s `getGeneratedKeys` method.

More generally, don't use NULL as a placeholder for 'please auto-increment my column here' - that's db specific. Why not `insert into Cart () values ();`? simpler, and shorter. Same goes for Artical (don't you mean 'Article'?) - `INSERT INTO Article(title, price, cart_id) VALUES ('some book', 20, idIGotFromGetGeneratedKeys);`

Answer (score 1):

try avoid the null value for id and use a select with the literal value .. instead of  asubqiery col cart_id only

```
INSERT INTO Artical(title,price,cart_id) 
select 'some book',20, Cart.id 
from Cart 
join Artical as ar on  Cart.id = ar.cart.id
```